# IRC бот на Python: Как сделать так, что бы вопрос и ответ можно было менять во время работы бота, а не останавливать его и править исходник?

Tags: python, бот, irc

Я написал простецкого бота для IRC на python, который работает из консоли. Он в бесконечном цикле опрашивает сервер и реагирует на команды, как написано в коде. Как сделать интерфейс взаимодействия с ним, пока он работает?

**UPDATE:** Окей, извиняюсь за неточный вопрос, я просто сам до конца не определился что мне конкретно нужно, но вот пример: бот задает вопрос и реагирует на правильный ответ. Как сделать так, что бы вопрос и ответ можно было менять во время работы бота, а не останавливать его и править исходник?

Comment: А точно нужно взаимодействовать с ним именно в процессе выполнения, или может лучше перезапустить с новыми параметрами?
Добавьте конкретики: что за команды выполняет, что требуется, чтобы выполнял
В принципе ничего не мешает добавить где-нибудь в цикле проверку на KeyPress, но что-то мне подсказывает, что такая логика может быть ошибочной

Comment: Какой интерфейс нужен уточните. Можно через pipe, можно GUI, можно консольный. Масса вариантов.

Comment: так вы же в нём уже реализовали «нитерфейс взаимодействия». и сами пишете, что «он реагирует на команды». что же ещё требуется?

Comment: Обновление вопроса не вносит ясности: можно иметь INI-файл со списком вопросов-ответов, можно иметь Pipe через который боту шлются подобного рода команды. Можно иметь GUI под это дело.

Comment: Ну GUI мне точно не нужен, я бы хотел работать из консоли. А про Pipe можно по подробнее?

Comment: @Ivan123 Гуглите по "named pipe", например. Можно еще погуглить по "Python IPC"

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать так, что бы вопрос и ответ можно было менять во время работы бота, а не останавливать его и править исходник?

Распространённый метод это отредактировать конфигурационный файл (c вопросами/ответами в данном случае) и сказать  сервису, чтобы он перегрузил конфигурацию. Например,

```
# initctl reload snort
```

Эта команда посылает `SIGHUP` сигнал snort процессу.

В Питон-скрипте, можно написать:

```
import signal

reload_config = True
def sighup_handler(*args):
    global reload_config
    reload_config = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, sighup_handler)

while True:
    if reload_config:
       reload_config = False
       # load config here
    # next Q & A here
```

Помимо сигнала, можно и на другие события также реагировать (нажатие клавиши, запись в стандартный ввод или socket/file/pipe).

Если реализовать поддержку нормального выхода (по SIGTERM, SIGINT), позволяя завершить текущую итерацию вопросов/ответов, то проще перезапустить скрипт, если есть необходимость обновить его конфигурацию/исходный код:

```
# initctl restart bot
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтение вопросов и ответов из файла? Меняем файл и всё.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

через пайпы, системV либо shared memory
самые быстрые варианты

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]